# Trying to print multiple components on separate pages using react-to-print

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-to-print

I'm using `react-to-print` and I have a list of components I want printed each on its separate page. When pressing on the button I get the error `Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent. Keys: 0,1`

I have a ref array:

```
const qrRefs = useRef([]);
```

This is the component list:

```
{rowSelection.map((el, i) => (
     <p key={i} ref={(el) => (qrRefs.current[i] = el)}>
         {el.id}
     </p>
))}
```

This is the print function

```
const handlePrintQR = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => qrRefs.current,
    copyStyles: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it using CSS!
I created a containing div for the array and gave it a ref

```
<div ref={qrRef}>
  {rowSelection.map((el, i) => (
    <p
      key={i}
      style={{ breakAfter: "page" }}
    >
      {el.id}
    </p>
  ))}
</div>
```

The `breakAfter: "page"` property in the `style` of the `<p>` tag breaks the printing page after each component so I get each component in separate page!